# 2 canvases are not working in Single HTML Form

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on application where on single page user have to sign two time in two different canvas. Below is the Code Snippet.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('signature');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var drawing = false;
var prevX, prevY;
var currX, currY;
var signature = document.getElementsByName('signature')[0];

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start);


var canvas = document.getElementById('signature2');

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var drawing = false;
var prevX, prevY;
var currX, currY;
var signature2 = document.getElementsByName('signature2')[0];

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start);




function start(e) {
  drawing = true;
}

function stop() {
  drawing = false;
  prevX = prevY = null;
  signature.value = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function draw(e) {
  if (!drawing) {
    return;
  }
  // Test for touchmove event, this requires another property.
  var clientX = e.type === 'touchmove' ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.clientX;
  var clientY = e.type === 'touchmove' ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY;
  currX = clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  currY = clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  if (!prevX && !prevY) {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  prevX = currX;
  prevY = currY;
}
```

```css
canvas#signature {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

canvas#signature2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

form>* {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form   method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="submit">
    <div>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your name"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="signature" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="signature2" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="signature2" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  <form>
```

**Problem**

Using above code canvas is only working in 2nd box, while in first box it is not working.

**How can i draw in both boxes different signature ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your JavaScript is that you declare the variables twice. First `var canvas` is referring to the first canvas element and 12 lines after the same variable is declared again, now with the second canvas element. And the same goes for all the other (global) variables.

To avoid this issue you need either different variables (like `var canvas1 = ...` and `var canvas2 = ...`) OR you avoid using global variables because it does not scale and it is confusing. An alternative in this situation is to put variables that you need as properties on the canvas element itself. An example is the `drawing` variable that is a property on each canvas element.

All the callback functions (`start`, `stop` and `draw`) have a parameter called `e` (the event object). On that object you can find the `target` that always refers to the canvas element, And on the canvas element you can find the `drawing` (`e.target.drawing`) that was defined up front. The same is true for the `prevX` and `prevY` that are both part of an object called `position`.

In the callback function `draw()` you can see that I find the canvas context (`ctx`), again based on the `e.target`.

```js
/*
 find all the relavant canvas elements
 and call forEach to loop through the array
*/
document.querySelectorAll('form canvas').forEach(canvas => {
  // properties for the canvas element
  canvas.drawing = false;
  canvas.position = {
    prevX: undefined,
    prevY: undefined
  };
  // mouse event listeners on the canvas element
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start);
  // touch event listeners on the canvas element
  canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start);
});

function start(e) {
  e.target.drawing = true;
}

function stop(e) {
  let canvas = e.target;
  canvas.drawing = false;
  canvas.position.prevX = canvas.position.prevY = null;
  let id = canvas.id;
  document.forms.form01[id].value = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function draw(e) {
  let canvas = e.target;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (!canvas.drawing) {
    return;
  }
  // Test for touchmove event, this requires another property.
  let clientX = e.type === 'touchmove' ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.clientX;
  let clientY = e.type === 'touchmove' ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY;
  let currX = clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  let currY = clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  if (!canvas.position.prevX && !canvas.position.prevY) {
    canvas.position.prevX = currX;
    canvas.position.prevY = currY;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.position.prevX, canvas.position.prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  canvas.position.prevX = currX;
  canvas.position.prevY = currY;
}
```

```css
body {
  /* can be added to prevent the page from scrolling when drawing on a mobile device */
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

canvas#signature {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

canvas#signature2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

form>* {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form01" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="submit">
    <div>
      <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <canvas id="signature" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <canvas id="signature2" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="signature2" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is fine but why i am not getting the both signatures after submitting the form ?

Comment: No, I just left that out in the first place. Now, I added it again. I added a name to the form and added the line in the stop function where the data URL is added as value to the hidden fields.

Comment: I added these 3 events for working on mobile, but it is not drawing .  canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", draw);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", start);

Comment: can you guide me how can i make it that i can draw also on mobile ?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer The event listeners that you list should work. I added them to the example. I also added a header that controls the scaling of the page on mobile devices. And added a body selector in the CSS. Right now (here on ST) it is not in use, but could be useful.